# SPO - open <a>hyperlink in modal

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, modal-dialog

I'm using SharePoint Online

I found this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-open-sharepoint-application-page-in-modal-dialog-popup-using-javascript) on how to open a hyperlink in Modal -- but how do I apply it in my  tag? clicking the link doesn't do anything.

```
<script>
function openModelDialogPopup(strPageURL) {  
var dialogOptions = {  
url: ‘https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/item/newifs.aspx’,  
title: ‘ModalDialog’,  
allowMaximize: false,  
showClose: true,  
width: 800,  
height: 330  
};  
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', dialogOptions);  
return false;  
}   

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openModelDialogPopup">CALL-IN</a>
```

Comment: try `openModeDialogPopup()` and remove the `strPageURL` in line 2

Comment: @Mike - I tried and still does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

replace your while `<script>` block with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">function openModeDialogPopup() { 
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
url: "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/item/newifs.aspx", 
title: "ModalDialog", 
allowMaximize: false, 
showClose: true,
width: 800,  
height: 330  
}); 
}; 

</script>
```